# Redmine+Issues_tree plugin - Internal error

Tags: plugins, ubuntu-16.04, redmine

Guys im having an issue with a plugin in Redmine using Ubuntu 16.04.

The plugin appears in the Administration->Plugin but when I visit the issues page and click on View Issues using Issues_tree plugin it throws an Internal Error 500.

Here is my production.log, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help?

```
Started GET "/redmine/" for 192.168.1.115 at 2017-07-19 13:51:58 +1200
Started GET "/redmine/projects" for 192.168.1.115 at 2017-07-19 13:51:58             +1200
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Current user: admin (id=1)
Processing by ProjectsController#index as HTML
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/base (32.4ms)
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered projects/index.html.erb within layouts/base (47.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 547ms (Views: 396.5ms | ActiveRecord: 51.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 484ms (Views: 334.1ms | ActiveRecord: 31.5ms)
Started GET "/redmine/projects/skylink-master" for 192.168.1.115 at 2017-07-    19 13:52:00 +1200
Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"skylink-master"}
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered projects/_members_box.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered projects/show.html.erb within layouts/base (25.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 158ms (Views: 77.9ms | ActiveRecord: 19.1ms)
Started GET "/redmine/projects/skylink-master/issues" for 192.168.1.115 at     2017-07-19 13:52:03 +1200
Processing by IssuesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"skylink-master"}
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered     plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues_trees/_issues_index_header_tags.htm    l.haml (6.9ms)
  Rendered     plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues_trees/_link_to_tree_view.html.haml     (32.7ms)
  Rendered queries/_filters.html.erb (14.8ms)
  Rendered queries/_columns.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered queries/_query_form.html.erb (25.5ms)
  Rendered issues/_list.html.erb (25.6ms)
  Rendered issues/_sidebar.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues/index.html.erb     within layouts/base (119.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 283ms (Views: 138.7ms | ActiveRecord: 19.3ms)
Started POST "/redmine/projects/skylink-    master/issues_trees/redirect_with_params" for 192.168.1.115 at 2017-07-19     13:52:05 +1200
Processing by IssuesTreesController#redirect_with_params as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "set_filter"=>"1", "sort"=>"id", "f"=>    ["status_id", ""], "op"=>{"status_id"=>"o"}, "group_by"=>"", "t"=>[""],     "project_id"=>"skylink-master"}
  Current user: admin (id=1)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
Started GET "/redmine/projects/skylink-master/issues_trees/tree_index?    f%5B%5D=status_id&f%5B%5D=&group_by=&op%5Bstatus_id%5D=o&project_id=skylink-    master&set_filter=1&sort=id&t%5B%5D=" for 192.168.1.115 at 2017-07-19 13:52:05     +1200
Processing by IssuesTreesController#tree_index as HTML
  Parameters: {"f"=>["status_id", ""], "group_by"=>"", "op"=>    {"status_id"=>"o"}, "project_id"=>"skylink-master", "set_filter"=>"1",     "sort"=>"id", "t"=>[""]}
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered 

plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues_trees/_link_to_plain_view.html.haml (2.9ms)
  Rendered queries/_filters.html.erb (16.3ms)
  Rendered queries/_columns.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues_trees/_tree_list.html.haml (21.0ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues_trees/tree_index.html.haml within layouts/base (73.1ms)
**Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 133ms (ActiveRecord: 12.3ms)**

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)):
    18:             = check_box_tag 'check_all', '', false, class: 'toggle-selection',
    19:                                                     title: "#{l(:button_check_all)}/#{l(:button_uncheck_all)}"
    20:           - query.inline_columns.each do |column|
    21:             = column_header(column)
    22:       %tbody
    23:         - issues.each do |issue|
    24:           = render partial: 'tree_node',
  app/helpers/queries_helper.rb:164:in `column_header'
  plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues_trees/_tree_list.html.haml:21:in `block (2 levels) in _plugins_redmine_issues_tree_app_views_issues_trees__tree_list_html_haml__1679904341144439480_18259740'
  plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues_trees/_tree_list.html.haml:20:in `each'
  plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues_trees/_tree_list.html.haml:20:in `block in _plugins_redmine_issues_tree_app_views_issues_trees__tree_list_html_haml__1679904341144439480_18259740'
  plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues_trees/_tree_list.html.haml:11:in `_plugins_redmine_issues_tree_app_views_issues_trees__tree_list_html_haml__1679904341144439480_18259740'
  plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/issues_trees/tree_index.html.haml:76:in `_plugins_redmine_issues_tree_app_views_issues_trees_tree_index_html_haml__19842071886702907_32334760'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'


Started GET "/redmine/admin" for 192.168.1.115 at 2017-07-19 13:52:13 +1200
Processing by AdminController#index as HTML
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (15.6ms)
  Rendered admin/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (18.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (18.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 59ms (Views: 43.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
Started GET "/redmine/admin/plugins" for 192.168.1.115 at 2017-07-19 13:52:17 +1200
Processing by AdminController#plugins as HTML
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered admin/plugins.html.erb within layouts/admin (4.4ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (18.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 38ms (Views: 29.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
Started GET "/redmine/settings/plugin/redmine_issues_tree" for 192.168.1.115 at 2017-07-19 13:52:18 +1200
Processing by SettingsController#plugin as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"redmine_issues_tree"}
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_issues_tree/app/views/settings/_redmine_issues_tree.html.haml (3.9ms)
  Rendered settings/plugin.html.erb within layouts/admin (12.2ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (7.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (20.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 45.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
Started POST "/redmine/settings/plugin/redmine_issues_tree" for 192.168.1.115 at 2017-07-19 13:52:21 +1200
Processing by SettingsController#plugin as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"Hidden==", "commit"=>"Apply", "id"=>"redmine_issues_tree"}
  Current user: admin (id=1)
**Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)**

NoMethodError (undefined method `permit!' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:70:in `plugin'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. 

Environment:
  Redmine version                3.4.1.stable
  Ruby version                   2.3.1-p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  Rails version                  4.2.8
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Git                            2.7.4
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_issues_tree            0.0.10
  redmine_messenger              1.0.0
  redmine_theme_changer          0.3.0

Comment: Please add this comment detail in question. 
Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here.

Comment: Thanks Ankit, I have looked over the previous questions and none of them relate to my issue. I have installed Redmine Version 3.4.0. I have then installed the redmine_issues_tree-master plugin. Did you want a description of all the commands I used?

Comment: See this suggestion. 1. Please add what you have done so far. 2.Don't dump all of your code here. post only that code which is not working or you didn't get what the code is doing. 3. Add description about errors and where you get the error (which line)  4. Add proper relevant description which proper describes your question. Thanks you